# how would I map a list of strings with a known format to a list of tuples?

Tags: scala, string, functional-programming

I have an array of strings. Each string has 2 parts and is separated by white space. Looks like:

```
 x <white space> y
```

I want to turn it into an array of Tuples where each tuple has (x, y)

How can I write this in scala? I know it will need something similar to:

```
val results = listOfStrings.collect { str => (str.left, str.right) }
```

not sure how i can break up each str to the left and right sides needed...

Answer (score 6):

You could take advantage of the fact that in Scala, Regular expressions are also "[extractors](http://ikaisays.com/2009/04/04/using-pattern-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-scala/)".

```
scala> var PairWithSpaces = "(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)".r                            
PairWithSpaces: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.+)\s+(.+)

scala> val PairWithSpaces(l, r) = "1     17"
l: String = 1    
r: String = 17
```

Now you can build your extractor into a natural looking "map":

```
scala> Array("a   b", "1 3", "Z x").map{case PairWithSpaces(x,y) => (x, y) }
res10: Array[(String, String)] = Array((a,b), (1,3), (Z,x))
```

Perhaps overkill for you, but can really help readability if your regex gets fancy.  I also like how this approach will fail fast if an illegal string is given.

Warning, not sure if the regex matches exactly what you need...

Answer (score 3):

You could (assuming that you want to drop without complaint any string that doesn't fit the pattern):

```
val results = listOfStrings.map(_.split("\\s+")).collect { case Array(l,r) => (l,r) }
```

Comment: Include `view` for potential runtime savings.

Comment: @Raphael - Between `listOfStrings` and `map`, yes, potentially.  But I don't think it'll be that noticeable given that `split` generates a regex, an array, and at least one string.  One extra `::` object on top of that is probably not that significant.

Comment: They I way understand `view`, many thusly created split results will never be written to the heap (i.e. those that are filtered out), whereas they are whithout `view`. I can't say what the impact is, though.

Comment: I think the complexity of what is going on here is too great for even `-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis` to simplify, so things _will_ be on the heap.  But they'll be in the youngest area of the heap, and won't stay alive for long, so if there's a lot of data it could make a difference to garbage collection.  For anything that isn't approaching the size of the whole memory, though, it shouldn't matter; the objects created by splitting will appear on the heap one by one or all at once, and then eventually will get cleared out.